# Identify Phonegap mobile application from JS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

We are building a web-application that provides an ability for users to create their own mobile app and manage it's content in their profile. Mobile application has similar functional for all our users, the only thing that is different - it's content. So, when one guy comes and creates a mobile app in our web-service and then he adds some news, photos, etc - his mobile app should display only his news and photos, the other guy will have his own mobile app with his own news and photos.

To get the content for a particular app we have unique API KEY, using this API KEY mobile application would make a request to our API to get unique content.

But the main problem is, that we don't know how to embed this API KEY in mobile application.

Here is the situation:

- we use Phonegap to create mobile applications, the original code is HTML+JS. To build applications we use Phonegap Build API, that requires a JS application to be delivered from Github repository or as ZIP archive. As the only thing that differs is content (HTML+JS codebase is the same for each user application), we've decided to use single Github repository for all user applications. Also, it would be easier to maintain one repository than multiple ones
- we use Phonegap Build API to automatically create a mobile application for user. So when user presses "CREATE" - the Phonegap mobile app is being created using Github repository code. Phonegap Build API 'create' method allows to set a title, description, version, package, etc of the application. So each application will have some custom settings. This settings are configurable before and after application build happens, so we can change title or version or package.

In this case, JS code is identical in each application and we can't hardcode unique api key in JS code to make API calls. We can use these configurable options (title, description, etc), the best one is "package", where we can set a unique application identifier (for instance "com.application.user1app"), but the problem is that we can't get them in JS after application was built, directly on device. We've already found some custom phonegap plugins, that were able to get application version or application name inside JS, but they are out-of-date or not longer supported, Phonegap default plugins don't have this functional too. As we are not native mobile developers it is a problem for us to write a custom plugin (or maybe you know any plugin for phonegap 3.1.0 that would return a package name of an app, it will help a lot)

**The question is**: what do you think, are there any other methods to identify from JS of built app what concrete user's app is running? to identify where should mobile app make API calls? (in case that we can't hardcode API KEY and we don't have a plugin).

Our plan is not strict, so if there won't be any other methods, we'll ask for a custom plugin or modify a scheme of application creation process. 
Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use the device UUID instead of an api key? you could get unique content for each device. if you really want to use an api key, it could be sent to the device at first connection and stored in the local storage.

Comment: @QuickFix, One application can be installed on multiple devices, we don't need to identify the device but an application that is running on a device. One app comes for one website user, not one device. If we have a lot of user applications, we want to know what application makes a request to API, information about device does not give this info. To send API key to a device at the very first connection, we should know what application is requesting it, to get API key for exactly that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @spezzino and @codevision, the solution that I've used for now is kinda mix of yours.
As a source code for mobile app build(Phonegap) is stored on GitHub, I've came with the following sequence of actions:

1) When new application is requested, `client.json` is being created (using GitHub API) with the following contents:

```
{ "api-key": "applicationapikeygoeshere" }
```

Repository will now have commited `client.json` file.

2) Build request is sent to Phonegap Build API, it uses a code from repository. For now repo contains `client.json` from the latest commit, so app will have it too.

3) After successful Phonegap build `client.json` is being removed from repository (using GitHub API), repository comes to it's initial state, we'll be able to build next app using this repository without conflicts.

4) Then in mobile app `client.json` is fetched via `requirejs` and parsed, to use api key

Maybe it is not very flexible and extendable, but the shortest and pretty painless solution for my problem, don't have to use additional servers for builds or repository for each application.

By the way, as an intermediate step (2.5) we are creating a reference(tag) to a particular commit, when config was uploaded (again, using GitHub API). So on GutHub we have quick access to all releases.

[GitHub API to create/delete files](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/)

[GitHub API to create a reference to commit](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to keep all you client-specific configuration options in the separate JS file, let's name it client.js.
This file would be generated as part of your build process, and you could put in it in the ZIP file with other source code for mobile application.

**client.js**

```
var clientSettings = {
    apiId: "API-ID",
    apiSecret: "Your Secret",
}
```

**client.js usage**

```
if (clientSettings !== undefined) {
     // Your mobile specific code goes here, take API keys, version, platform etc.
     // what ether you put in client.js could be accessed from here
} else {
     // We are running from the browser. Go different path and use other API
}
```

as a precaution, I would recommend add client.js to the .gitignore

Comment: As Phonegap build service has restrictions on a number of hosted private applications, we had to refuse the usage of ZIP archives (available only for private apps) and it was not the best solution for us to deal with archives. So we need to modify client.js for each app going to be built or have a github repo for each app with custom client.js, both seems not the best solution for us

Comment: By the way, we use Grunt to build a JS project, so it could be possible to create custom client.js, but we don't want to involve this into user application build process, as it will be more complicated - extra server to build JS app using grunt, create own repository for that app, and only then perform actions that we have now. It requires more steps to be accomplished, now we deal with the Github repo only, not caring about JS part

Comment: You could take values from config.xml in the root of www/ folder for platforms as in example mentioned by spezzino. In Cordova 3.3 that file definitely here for Android and for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the config.xml file before build (to include package name and title), you can put an apiKey there, and then read using jQuery using this method

```
$.get("config.xml", function(data){
    alert($(data).find('widget').attr('apiKey'));
});


<widget id="com.example.hello" version="1.0.0" apiKey="API_KEY_HERE">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
</widget>
```

Comment: I also had this kind of idea, and have tested it now after your answer. Seems that this config.xml, used for build, is not stored after build anymore. I've downloaded compiled *.apk application for android, extracted files and the only config.xml I've found was "/res/xml/config.xml", but I couldn't reach it via AJAX. also, my app had package id "com.phonegap.hello-world", but when I used a search for the word "world" through these extracted files it gave nothing. A search for custom "apiKey" attribute failed too.